# Dojo Programmatically validate TextBox

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to create a dojo form programmatically and validate input TextBox on button click. But when I try to valid I get an error "dijit.byId(..) is undefined. Below is the code:

```
var form = new dijit.form.Form({ 
                                    nametb: new dijit.form.TextBox({
                                        name: "name",
                                        type: "text",
                                        required: true,
                                        placeHolder: "Your Full Name"
                                    },"nametb"),
                                    subBtn: new dijit.form.Button({
                                        label: "Proceed",
                                        onClick: function(){
                                            if(dijit.byId("nametb").get('value') == null || dijit.byId("nametb").get('value').length == 0 )
                                                {
                                                    alert("Please enter Name");
                                                    return false;
                                                }

                                        }
                                    }),
                                    cnclBtn: new dijit.form.Button({
                                        label: "Cancel",
                                        onClick: function(){
                                            dia.hide();
                                        }
                                    }),
                                    postCreate: function(){
                                        this.domNode.appendChild(this.nametb.domNode);
                                        this.domNode.appendChild(this.subBtn.domNode);
                                        this.domNode.appendChild(this.cnclBtn.domNode);
                                    }
                                });
```

But now when I click the Proceed button I get an error `dijit.byId(...) is undefined`

How can I validate this TextBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never set an id for `nametb`, so `dijit.byId()` isn't able to find the textbox and throws an error. Try

```
nametb: new dijit.form.TextBox({
    name: "name",
    type: "text",
    id: "nametb",
```

Comment: I did as you said but it still allows the form to be submitted. After a long struggle I added dijit.byId("nametb").get('value').length == 0 as well to get it to work. See changes on question.

Comment: @zulq Are you still having any problems?

Comment: @zulq You're still not assigning an `id` to `nametb` in your OP.

Comment: I just didn't show the full copy paste code. I just edited the one here but my code has an id. It's working fine now but only with the length check as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this on specified widget :

```
// validate nametb textbox
dijit.byId("nametb").validate();
```

Or you can validate the form like this:

```
if (dijit.byId("yourForm").validate()) { 
   // do something if your form is valid
} else {
   // show error message
}
```